# Dimension of complex on 2-sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Given a 2-sphere $S^2$ and a set of points $A$ embedded on its surface, if we were to consider a pair of points $(a,b) \in A$, and construct each point's $k$-nearest neighbor set, say $K(a)$ and $K(b)$, respectively. We add an edge or arc (along the surface of the sphere) between $a$ and $b$, if $K(a) \cap K(b) \neq \emptyset$ (non-empty intersection) and do this for all possible pairs in $A$. If we were to then construct a simplicial complex $X$ from such a graph defining the **cliques (complete subgraphs)** as **simplices**, can $dim(X) >2$? I ask because I imagine that at best I can only arrive at $2$-simplices (triangles), as these edges can overlap for a $4$-clique?

Comment: What if $k$ is so big that $K(a)=A$ for all $a$?

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Even then, wouldn't I at best only get triangles then?

Comment: As an abstract graph it can easily be complete. Unless you are thinking of something embedded in the sphere but even then you can have 4 vertices of a regular inscribed tetrahedron all pairwise connected.

Comment: Could you please define $k$-nearest neighbor set?

Comment: What do you mean by "the surface of the sphere"?

Comment: @Matt Given a point x, we find the $k$ nearest points to $x$ on the sphere using the gedesic distance as a metric (in this case "great-circle distance).

Comment: @PaulFrost on the boundary of the sphere.

Comment: The $2$-sphere is  $S^2 = \{ x \in \mathbb R^3 \mid \lVert x \rVert = 1\}$. It is the surface (or equivalently the boundary) of the $3$-ball $D^3 = \{ x \in \mathbb R^3 \mid \lVert x \rVert \le 1\}$.